# mysql calculation result forcefully rounded

Tags: mysql, decimal, rounding

I have this field:

```
user_id VARCHAR(20);
insert_date DATE;
fgps DECIMAL(5,2);
```

in a table, and is calculating the value using these (simplified) statements:

```
-- @num1, 2 and 3 are SET with some query to get the values    
SET @gps_average := ((@num1 + @num2 + @num3) / 3.0);
INSERT INTO user_gps VALUES(:user_id, :insert_date, @gps_average);
```

The script is working fine, except for one thing --  the result of @gps_average is forced to be rounded by the mysql server. i.e. if I have the values

```
@num1=3, @num2=4, @num3=4
```

I should get 3.67 stored in fgps, but instead 4.00 is what I got.

What have I done wrong or how do I force the server to no round up my values?

I've done similar calculations on some other fields and the values are stored with decimal values correctly, but not in this case, this is driving me crazy...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can not be reproduced. See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9c1e/1/0 Must be an issue with your code, but not with MySQL.

Comment: how is your @num1..3 defined? have you tried  declare them as decimal ?

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT @gps_average := ((@num1 + @num2 + @num3) / 3.0);`?

Comment: Rick James: If I run the script in PHPMyAdmin, I get 3.66666 for @fgps.

Comment: I've decided to use the front end (C++) to do the calculation for this part, as a workaround, so the problem will still remains as a mystery :(. Anyway , if anyone can provide a reason or solution, I'd be much appreciating the effort, thanks for everyone who has been trying to help.